# React-Query, useQuery returns undefined only after loading is complete

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-query

I am using the react-query package in my react app. I have a pattern going which uses useQuery to get data from an api with axios. Multiple endpoints work except a GET search/params endpoint. Axios returns the expected data but once loading is complete in useQuery, undefined is returned.

```
import React from "react";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import { api } from "../../../api";

export const useSearch = (query) => {
  const searchResults = useQuery(
    api.clubhouse.searchCacheKey(query),
    api.clubhouse.search({ params: { query: query } })
  );

  let searchData = [];

  let isLoading = searchResults.isLoading;

  if (!isLoading) {
    searchData = searchResults.data;
  }

  return { searchData, isLoading };
};
```

Once `isLoading: false`, `searchResults` becomes undefined and I see this error `TypeError: config.queryFn.apply is not a function`. If I log inside the `api.clubhouse.search` (which contains the axios call) I can see the correct data. This pattern works fine for other api calls as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that this may be your issue:

```
api.clubhouse.search({ params: { query: query } })
```

The `search` function here I am guessing is returning a promise, but you need to pass in a function to `useQuery` that returns a promise instead of the promise itself.  So, maybe make a change like this:

```
const searchResults = useQuery(
  api.clubhouse.searchCacheKey(query),
  () => api.clubhouse.search({ params: { query: query } })
);
```

Comment: This seemed to work! Not sure why my other useQuery functions worked but oh well... Thanks!

Comment: probably because they didn’t have any parameters. If you pass in `api.clubhouse.search` you pass in the function itself. But if you invoke the function you pass in the result.