# React useQuery hook running all the time inside the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I have a problem where useQuery is always running in my application and I don't why

In my component

```
import { GET_DATA } from 'apiCalls';
const {  loading, error, data } = useQuery('getData', GET_DATA(token));
```

In my api call

```
export const GET_DATA = async (token) => {
try {
    const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER}/api/...`, {
        headers: {'auth-token': token},
    });
    console.log(res);
    return res.data;
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Error getting data');
    return err;
}
```

}

when I debug my app. The function GET_DATA is always running ALL the time. what is the issue here ?

Comment: I think in some point in your app you are using useEffect and inside the useEffect  you are doing something that makes the component to rerender.
if you provide more information on the component that you are using GET_DATA in it, I can tell you where is the problem.

Comment: I Don't even have useEffect in my component @Ako

Comment: I checked my component and the problem is useQuery 100% since when I comment it the component stop always rerendering @Ako

Comment: you must not call the function inside useQuery. I write the answer how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

You must provide the useQuery only the function it wants to run, you must not call it inside useQuery. Provide the token to GET_DATA this way:

#### EDIT

As [@tkdodo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8405310/tkdodo) said we don't need to use the async function.

```
const {  loading, error, data } = useQuery('getData', ()=>{
   return GET_DATA(token);
});
```

**The first solution I provided was this:**

```
const {  loading, error, data } = useQuery('getData', async()=>{
   const data = await GET_DATA(token);
   return data;
});
```

Comment: This syntax is unnecessary convoluted as opposed to just `() => GET_DATA(token)`

Comment: @TkDodo Yes, you are right, we don't need to use async function.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is the same as in [React-Query, useQuery returns undefined only after loading is complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68669408/react-query-usequery-returns-undefined-only-after-loading-is-complete)

The `queryFn` needs to be a function that returns a promise. `GET_DATA` does that. But by doing

`GET_DATA(token)` you directly invoke the function. So you’ll likely want:

`() => GET_DATA(token)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
// apiCalls.js
export const getData = async (token) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER}/api/...`, {
        headers: {'auth-token': token},
    });
    return res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error getting data');
    return err;
}

// Component.js
import { getData } from 'apiCalls';

function Component(){
  const {  loading, error, data } = useQuery(
    'getData', 
    ()=>GET_DATA(token)
  );

  return (
    <div>...</div>
  )
}
```

`useQuery` should run in the component and the second parameter should not be a promise, but a function that returns a promise.